# How to stream captured packets via UDP? tcpdump or other tool

Tags: linux, udp, tcpdump, pcap

I want to capture traffic or router and send it to remote host via `tzcp` or other udp proto.

How to stream captured packets via UDP? tcpdump or other tool

Use case:

Linux box connected to internet without white ip.
Connected to interested network.

I run tool with parameters 'arp or icmp' and stream udp packets containing this packets to remote host.

On remote host using `scapy` i can analyze remote traffiс.

Answer (score -1):

Tcpdump can do all the work for capturing UDP packets and storing them as described below and then use can use WireShark for streaming these packets

```
tcpdump -i <interface> udp port <udp_port> -w udp_packets.pcap
```

Comment: no, i will update question.